# python asyncio.Future cancelling on its own

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following chunk of code:

```
    async def hold(self, request_key):
        logger.info(f"HOLDING: request_key={request_key}")
        ongoing_rating_perishable = self.__held_requests.pop(request_key, None)
        if ongoing_rating_perishable is None:
            future = asyncio.get_running_loop().create_future()
            rating_perishable = RatingRequestPerishable(request_key, future, holding=True)
            self.__held_requests.add(rating_perishable)
        else:
            future = ongoing_rating_perishable.rating_future

        try:
            print(f"state: {future._state}")
            result = await future
        except asyncio.CancelledError as err:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            raise

        return result
```

That inexplicably results every other time in this exception being raised.

```
  File "...", line ..., in hold
    result = await future
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

The future is not explicitly cancelled by me anywhere in the code, neither is the event loop terminating, neither I can find an explanation anywhere. Also, yes the future was pending before awaiting. Anyone has a clue?

Comment: This error does not necessarily mean that there was an explicit call to future.cancel.  If the task enclosing the hold() function is cancelled when it's awaiting on future, then a CancelledError will be injected into the task at that point.  Your code indicates that you're printing the traceback from the CancelledError - perhaps you could post that.

Comment: Thanks Paul. This actually helped a bit. The hold function is called from a quart server endpoint. It seems that chrome was cancelling the request. However, I would have thought that on the event of a task cancelling, I would not even be able to catch any exceptions like I am doing. BTW, the stack trace is there in the original question. It is just that small!

Comment: Glad you found the problem.  For future reference, "cancelling" a task means exactly what I said: a "CancelledError" is injected into the program flow.  If you don't catch that exception (or re-raise it, as you have done) then the task will exit.  It's possible to catch it and handle it, which may cause the task to continue even though it's been cancelled.  CancelledError is NOT a subclass of Exception, so you won't accidentally catch it (with an `except Exception` expression) when you don't intend to.

Comment: @PaulCornelius you should put your comment in an answer, it was exactly my problem! doesn't help that there's absolutely no mention of this behavior in the docs >:(